# Generating and passing dynamic JSON request body to a POST API request in SoapUI using Groovy Script

Tags: json, api, groovy, automation, soapui

I am trying to generate dynamic JSON request body for an API automation using SOAP UI. I am using groovy script to do the same. 
I am not able to pass the dynamically generated property values to my JSON body in the request. Can someone please help?

My Groovy Script

```
import java.util.Random

//generating random values
Random rand = new Random()
String brandName = "BrandName" + rand.nextInt(100000)
String pageTitle = "BrandPageTitle" + rand.nextInt(100000)

//setting test case properties
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("name", brandName);
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("page_title", pageTitle);
```

Here is my JSON Body for the POST Request. I am not sure the way I am accessing the variables in the below JSON is correct

```
{
  "name": "${brandName}",
  "page_title": "${pageTitle}"
}
```

I also tried this. 'POSTCreateNewBrand' is my TestCase name and 'name' is the property_name

```
{
  "name": "${#POSTCreateNewBrand#name}",
  "page_title": "${#POSTCreateNewBrand#page_title}"
}
```

When I run my tests I see that the name field is not getting supplied as part of the request body and see the below error

```
<errors>
   <error>
      <status>400</status>
      <message>The required field 'name' was not supplied.</message>
   </error>
</errors>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use the properties in a `TestCase` level it's not necessary to use the `TestCase` name, use instead directly `#TestCase#` constant followed by your property name as follows:

```
{
  "name": "${#TestCase#name}",
  "page_title": "${#TestCase#page_title}"
}
```

Additionally the same applies for `Project`, `TestSuite` and so on; the name it's for `TestStep` level, from [SOAPUI documentation](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html):

> #Project# - references a Project property(Reference properties across a particular SoapUI project)
>
> #TestSuite# - references a TestSuite property in the containing TestSuite
>
> #TestCase# - references a TestCase property in the containing TestCase
>
> #MockService# - references a MockService property in the containing MockService
>
> #Global# - references a global property. Found in File>Preferences>Global Properties tab. Reference properties across all projects
>
> #System# - references a system property. Found in Help>System properties.
>
> #Env# - references an environment variable
>
> [TestStep name]# - references a TestStep property

Hope this helps,

Comment: That was pretty straightforward :) Thanks it worked!

Comment: @Sandeep nice to help you `:)`

Comment: @albciff

But how this body will get attached to payload

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal if you've a different question, please post a new one, explaining your specific problem and adding all necessary details :).

Comment: Super helpful, any idea where to access Custom Test Case Properties?

Comment: Hi @BobSmall you can access Test Case custom properties the same way using `${#TestCase#customProperyName}`